# CiviMail > New Mailing > No recipients Error

Tags: civimail

We've recently installed CiviCRM 4.6.6 and we're on WordPress 4.3. I'm experiencing the same issues as shown in this thread: [CiviMail Mailing - Unable to select group, getting error of No recipients](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3581/civimail-mailing-unable-to-select-group-getting-error-of-no-recipients)
When I go into New Mailing, No Recipients shows up on the right. I can't enter email addresses, I can't select a group, I'm stuck. If I use Search and select a group, and pick the Action to Send a Mass Mailing, the Mail screen has Recipients = Search Results, but still says No Recipients. I'm stuck. Since Mail won't work Debug and Backtrace can't either. I don't know what Ajax is, I'm not that techie. We're on DreamHost, no cpanel, but I can use FTP. Send Mail works and there's no one opted out or anything in my test group. This looks like a bug that's been around for a few months? How can I fix this??? Thanks, in advance...jim

Comment: I tried disabling all the WordPress plugins, except CiviCRM and it didn't help. I tried switching themes and it didn't help. On the Define Mailing screen, the groups don't show up when you click on the drop down arrow for the Recipients field. And it says No Recipients off to the right. What should I do???

Comment: I have Firebug installed in FireFox. I can figure out Ajax if I need to. This looks like a bug in CiviCRM 4.6.6, right? Should I install a newer version or an older version???

Comment: Can you answer DaveFF's comment on http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3581/civimail-mailing-unable-to-select-group-getting-error-of-no-recipients ?

Comment: Do your test contacts have on hold, do not email or bulk opt out set? **NO** Are their email addresses primary (they should be if they only have one each)? **YES** Is the group smart? **NO** One of the two email addresses is bad, so I could test that. I also tried entering the good email address directly into the Recipients field on the New Mailing screen. It'll let me type in the address but when I hit Tab it goes away. It says No Recipients off to the right, all the time. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay, you can't enter email address directly onto the Recipients field, you can only select the groups. So, can you perform some test steps here - create a test group (`Contact -> New Group`), check the Mailing list checkbox for `Group Type` field, Add some contacts (with valid email) in this group. Then check whether you can able to see this in `New Mailing` ?

Comment: OMG, I thought you found the problem...the Mailing checkbox was not set for any of my groups. (seems like default should be yes-checked). I turned the Mailing checked on for all my groups (Donor, Media, Volunteer, Test email group). I went into New Mailing and now the groups show up in the dropdown. Unfortunately, I can select all the groups and it estimates No Recipients?! That's over 1000 email addresses. The vast majority of them are valid.

Comment: This doesn't seems to be a bug to me, as i can successfully select groups on the standard demo server http://d46.demo.civicrm.org. Don't you see any contacts after selecting the test group you've created above ?

Comment: I changed my Test Email Group to include three valid addresses. I got rid of the bad address. I've studied all three records...my own and two friends. No one in the database is opted out yet or anything like that. I clicked on the little wrench next to the Recipients field in New Mailing. Dedupe by email is checked and the other fields are Automatic. I tried changing these settings to no avail. When I imported the 11,500+ contacts, it defaulted to Home and I left it that way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe this problem is specific to WordPress installations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28933/discussion-between-jimcrist-and-jitendra-purohit).

Comment: I can use New Mailing and send a test email to myself, no problem...

Comment: I just upgraded to 4.6.8 (my first upgrade!). But the same bug exists in that version too. I can't believe I'm the only person using 4.6 and WordPress and CiviMail...

Comment: I just installed 4.5.8 and that fixed the problem. Now I just have to reload 11,500+ contacts...500 at a time...ugh...why does import throw a 404 error?

Comment: I have the same problem on CiviCRM 4.6.11 on Joomla 2.5.28. When I select the group and it shows 0 recipient.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/3122)

Answer (score 0):

This > check the **Mailing list checkbox** for Group Type

Solved this issue for me.