# Can I go back to CiviCRM 4.5.8?

Tags: civimail

We've recently installed CiviCRM 4.6.6 and we're on WordPress 4.3. I've got a major problem with CiviMail (see [HERE](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/5182/civimail-new-mailing-no-recipients-error). No one has responded in six days. Is there backwards compatibility? Would it be safe to install 4.5.8?? At this point, we're just using the Contact table. I'd rather not import all the data again, since I could only do 600 records at a time (the command line doesn't support groups or dup checking). I've got to get this fixed...someone please help me!! thanks...jim

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you engage a professional to help you resolve the issue you experienced with 4.6.x, because then you'll have the bug fixed AND the security fixes which 4.5.x lacks.

Comment: We don't have the time or money to hire a php programmer to find this bug in CiviCRM/CiviMail. And we can't restore the old version (4.4) very easily, because we changed domain names and hosting services. It would be very helpful to know if this is a known bug in 4.6.6?? Has it been fixed in 4.6.8??

Answer (score 1):

The recommended method for downgrading is to restore to the backups you made before upgrading.

For contact data modified between when you upgraded and now, you'd need to either export your changes and import them to the 4.5.x system, or keep the upgraded system running and copy the data over.

I would not expect downgrading the DB directly to work, and I would expect manually reversing the DB changes between versions to be more complex than fixing your mail issue.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. This is useful. Has this problem been fixed in 4.6.8?

Comment: If it has, it ought to be documented over on https://issues.civicrm.org somewhere. I couldn't see any obvious candidates there though ... You might have some luck by getting in touch with the author of [this related question](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3581/civimail-mailing-unable-to-select-group-getting-error-of-no-recipients) and pooling resources to get the issue fixed?